# Задача (олимпиадная)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Замок имеет форму большого квадрата, составленного из N × N маленьких квадратиков. Внешние квадратики являются башнями, именно они играют основную роль в защите замка от неприятеля. Например, если замок имеет размер 4 × 4, то у него 12 башен (смотрите второй рисунок, башни на нем выделены серым цветом).

Замок охраняют K полков, которые необходимо разместить по башням. В одной башне можно разместить несколько полков, но при этом в каждой башне должен находиться хотя бы один полк, иначе неприятель легко захватит эту башню. Если все башни защищены, то неприятель выбирает для атаки одну из четырех сторон замка, которую защищает наименьшее число полков (то есть суммарное число полков во всех башнях данной стороны квадрата минимально).

Определите, как нужно разместить полки для наилучшей защиты замка.

Входные данные

Первая строка входных данных содержит число N — размер замка (2 ≤ N ≤ 100). Вторая строка входных данных содержит число K — количество полков, охраняющих замок (0 ≤ K ≤ 100).

Выходные данные

Выведите единственное число — количество полков на наименее укрепленной стороне замка при наилучшем размещении полков. Если имеющихся полков недостаточно для защиты всех башен, выведите число 0.

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
if n==0 or k==0:
    print(0)
elif n==1:
    print(k)
elif k<=n:
    print(1)
else:
    z =n**2
    d = (n-2)*(n-2)
    b = z-d
    o = n+(k-b)//2
    print(o)
```

Comment: В чем проблема?

Comment: Не знаю, просто машина не принимает ответ

Comment: Ну ошибка какая?

Comment: Там не уточняется

Comment: Ну блин когда код запускаешь?

Comment: Я не знаю, я не могу найти) Всё прекрасно работает, но компьютер не принимает ответ

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2593133.html

Comment: Какой, по-Вашему, должен быть ответ для `N = 2, K = 1`?

Comment: Спасибо за сайт, все прошел, но я так и не понял смысл задачи.. Там сравнение "Если башен больше, чем полков, то выводим 0", но я думаю, если полков 2, то ответ должен быть = 1, потому что эти полки можно по углам замка расположить

Comment: Yaant , действительно, тут моя большая ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
b = 4*(n-1)
if b > k:
  print(0)
else:
  print(n+(k-b)//2)
```